# How to validate arrays in forms in express-form

Tags: arrays, node.js, validation, express

While defining my route, I would like to be able to validate if an incoming parameter is an array and raise an error if it isn't. I have so far been using `express-form` for all validations and can't seem to find a way to validate arrays in it. I know I can use `express-validate` for a doing this but I would like to keep using what I've been using so far so that everything can look uniform.

```
app.post(
    '/addUserInfo',
    form(
        field('userID').trim().required().is(idRegex)
        // Need similar check for 'items' field here
    ),
    offline.addUserInfo
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [docs](https://github.com/dandean/express-form#custom-methods)!

You can use:

**Update**
As mentioned in comment the value is string so needs to be parsed to array

```
field('items').custom(function(value){ 

    // check if value is array, throw error if not 

    //if(value instanceof Array) return;

    if(JSON.parse(value) instanceof Array) return;

    throw new Error('The field "items" is not an array');

});
```

Comment: Oops I think I missed that. I got this to work by changing the `if` to `JSON.parse(value) instanceof Array`. Thank you :)